qualitype font for a cover
my texlive installation on Linux is new. I installed the qualitype font package to make a cover for my notes and run with 'xelatex' a simple 'test.tex' file with the content:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\title{qtflorencia-font}
\author{Marcel C. Tavelin}
\date{May 2024}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\setmainfont{QTFlorencia}
For mange Aar siden levede en Keiser, som holdt saa uhyre meget af
   smukke nye Kl\ae der, at han gav alle sine Penge ud for ret at blive
   pyntet. Han br\o d sig ikke om sine Soldater, br\o d sig ei om
   Comedie eller om at kj\o re i Skoven, uden alene for at vise sine
   nye Kl\ae der. Han havde en Kjole for hver Time paa Dagen, og
   ligesom man siger om en Konge, han er i Raadet, saa sagde man altid
   her: >>Keiseren er i Garderoben!<<~--
\end{document}


But, I got the following error..
kpathsea: Running mktextfm QTFlorencia
/home/tux/TeXLive2024/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation Q for QTFlorencia.
/home/tux/TeXLive2024/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /home/tux/TeXLive2024/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input QTFlorencia
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf QTFlorencia
! I can't find file `QTFlorencia'.
<*> ...r; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input QTFlorencia
                                                  
Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...r; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input QTFlorencia
                                                  
Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: QTFlorencia.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input QTFlorencia' failed to make QTFlorencia.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.


! Package fontspec Error: 
(fontspec)                The font "QTFlorencia" cannot be found; this may
(fontspec)                be but usually is not a fontspec bug. Either there
(fontspec)                is a typo in the font name/file, the font is not
(fontspec)                installed (correctly), or there is a bug in the
(fontspec)                underlying font loading engine (XeTeX/luaotfload).

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.16 F
      or mange Aar siden levede en Keiser, som holdt saa uhyre meget af
? 


Could anyone help me? Thank you all for the attention.

Welcome! How did you install TeX Live? If you comment out the \setmainfont line, does it compile? This is a sanity check since you say your installation is new. Make sure it works without the additional font before troubleshooting the font. What does fc-match QTFlorencia return? For example, I get QTFlorencia.otf: "QTFlorencia" "Medium" which means fontconfig can find it. And how did you install the font package? If you installed a full TeX Live, you wouldn't need to install it separately?

\setmainfont should probably be in your preamble, though that's not the problem here.

@cfr
I install TeX Live with the installer install-tl-unx.tar.gz that I download from tug.org and install in my Home directory. I follow the described in https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html ; select a num. of collection in Customize button an install ~ 6 Gb
yes, it compile with line \setmainfont commented. It's OK.
$ fc-match QTFlorencia -->
NotoSans-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans" "Regular"

OK. Good. Then I'm guessing that you haven't added the font directories to font config. You need to copy $(kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFSYSVAR)/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf into fontconfig's configuration directory. This will depend a bit on your Linux distro. On mine, I copied the file to /etc/fonts/conf.avail/09-texlive-fonts.conf and then created a symbolic link to that file from /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive-fonts.conf. This enables you to edit the file, if you wish, which you place in /etc/fonts/conf.avail. Then run fc-cache to update the cached font information.

@cfr Thanks to reply. I did what do you wrote but didn't work it. Still the same when I run   $ fc-match QTFlorencia ---> NotoSans-Regular.ttf: "Noto Sans" "Regular". When I try to compile the sample that I posted early return the same error.

What output did you get when you updated the cache? You did do this as root? Which Linux distro?

Hello @cfr and everyone. It worked. I had not put the number in the file name when I copy it in /etc/fonts/conf.avail; when I did the correction it worked. Thanks cfr, you went straight in the point, thanks a lot.

Ah, yes. fontcontig is extremely finnicky and order matters ;). The number changes the order in which the files are read.

Also, LuaLaTeX uses luaotfload to find fonts and does not have the same problem.

I don't think you want to make QTFlorencia the document's main font. By calling the file name, XeLaTeX will directly try in the TeX tree, so fontconfig doesn't matter.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\florencia}{QTFlorencia.otf}

\title{qtflorencia-font}
\author{Marcel C. Tavelin}
\date{May 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

{\florencia
For mange Aar siden levede en Keiser, som holdt saa uhyre meget af
   smukke nye Kl\ae der, at han gav alle sine Penge ud for ret at blive
   pyntet. Han br\o d sig ikke om sine Soldater, br\o d sig ei om
   Comedie eller om at kj\o re i Skoven, uden alene for at vise sine
   nye Kl\ae der. Han havde en Kjole for hver Time paa Dagen, og
   ligesom man siger om en Konge, han er i Raadet, saa sagde man altid
   her: >>Keiseren er i Garderoben!<<~--}

\bigskip

Now the text is in the standard font.

\end{document}



This is true, but there are other reasons to set up fontconfig for TeX Live fonts, such as making them available in other applications.
